# Why my action hook on function.php not excute?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a action hook on function.php in order to redirect url based on current day. Please see my code below. I tried with init hook/after_theme_setup hook but this code not execute. Please give me reason for this error.

```
<?php


function load_category_by_day(){
if( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ){
$current_day = strtolower( date('N') ); // 'monday', 'sunday', etc.

wp_safe_redirect( site_url( "/category/$current_day/" ) ); 
}
} 
add_action( 'init', 'load_category_by_day' );
?>
```

Comment: Your function definition is after add_action. Might this cause a problem?

Comment: sorry, i removed do_action( 'load_category_by_day' );, becuase init action have on wp-setting.php. And i tried function definition before add_action . But it still not run. @Zim84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function load_category_by_day(){

if( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ){
$current_day = strtolower( date('N') ); // 'monday', 'sunday', etc.

wp_safe_redirect( site_url( "/category/$current_day/" ) ); 

exit;
}
} 
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'load_category_by_day' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, so much! i got it :) :) I am very happy now (Y) Good luck for all (Y)